# jQuery if hasClass action

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have made this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4CtLV/

Now, what i'm trying to do, is if a tab has selectedTab as its class, then show the corresponding div. I've set up the if statement but am unsure where to go from here,

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this revision](http://jsfiddle.net/4CtLV/3/).

I have factored out the code to show a tab into a function `showTab`:

```
var showTab = function(id) {
    $tab = $("#" + id);
    $('.tabTrigger').removeClass('selectedTab');
    $tab.addClass('selectedTab');
    $('.tabContent').hide();
    $('#' + id.replace('tab','content')).show();
}
```

The rest is then very easy:

```
// Show the selected tab, or the first one if none is selected
var selectedId = $('.tabTrigger.selectedTab').attr('id');
showTab(selectedId || $('.tabTrigger:first').attr('id'));

// Set up the click handlers
$('.tabTrigger').click(function(){
    showTab(this.id);
});
```

As a general note, in all such cases you need to factor the code you want to run into a self-contained function. Once you do that, the rest comes naturally.

Comment: You don't really need to pass the id into showTab.  If you just call `$('.tabTrigger').click(showTab);` you can refer to `this` inside of the function.  You can use `click()` without a parameter to trigger the event on `.selectedTab` so its gets selected.

Comment: @Dennis: That's also possible. But I prefer it this way because you can use `showTab` independently of `click` handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.tabTrigger.selectedTab')` as the selector instead, and then use [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show) to show them:

```
$('.tabTrigger.selectedTab').show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattlunn/4CtLV/1/

Comment: But you also need to show the corresponding content (if it's not the first')

Comment: But i need to show the content that corresponds to the selected tab

Comment: @benhowdle89: In which case your Fiddle already works... http://jsfiddle.net/4CtLV/?

Answer (score 0):

Try my update: http://jsfiddle.net/4CtLV/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabContent:gt(0)').hide();
    $('.tabTrigger:first').addClass('selectedTab');
    var selectedTab = $('.tabTrigger.selectedTab:first');
    if (selectedTab.length == 1) {
        $('#' + selectedTab.attr('id').replace('tab', 'content')).show();
    }
    $('.tabTrigger').click(function() {
        $('.tabTrigger').removeClass('selectedTab');
        $(this).addClass('selectedTab');
        $('.tabContent').hide();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        id = id.replace('tab', 'content');

        $('#' + id).show();
    });
});
```